# How to execute a command when selecting an option and pressing 'ok' button in YAD?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, yad

I'm using YAD to create a "app store" with a GUI and I can't find any tutorial on how to execute a command when I select an option from a list and click on the 'ok' button ('ok' will be replaced with 'install'). I want to use shell script only.

This is the script I wrote. It's a simple list with 2 columns and 2 items in them. The windows icon is just a test.

```
yad --list --center --width=800 --height=600 
--title "apps4pi" \
--column "app name" --column "description" \
SimpleScreenRecorder " powerful feature packed yet simple and easy to use screen recorder" \
System-Tools "system maintenance commands all done for you"
```

Comment: What do you mean by the windows icon?

Comment: Is it ok to exit the dialog when you click on the 'install' button, and do the installing thereafter, or should it do the installing while `yad` is running?

Comment: I meant window icon, and i removed it from the code

Comment: yes, it's ok if yad exits while installing

Comment: Well, my answer offers both options: with and without exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code shows how to run some actions on a selected row:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT

# you can also double-click on a row to "install" it.

tmpfile=$(mktemp -p /dev/shm)
if output=$(yad \
--button='Exit!application-exit:1' \
--button='Exit and Install!system-run:0' \
--button="Install!system-run:/bin/sh -c \"cat $tmpfile >&2\"" \
--list \
--dclick-action="/bin/sh -c \"printf \%\s'\n' %s >&2\"" \
--select-action="/bin/sh -c \"printf \%\s'\n' %s >$tmpfile\"" \
--separator='\n' \
--center --width=800 --height=600 --title "apps4pi" \
--column "app name" --column "description" \
SimpleScreenRecorder "powerful feature packed yet simple and easy to use screen recorder" \
System-Tools "system maintanance commands all done for you"); then
    printf '%s\n' "$output" >&2
fi
```

The example command prints the columns of the row line by column in standard error device. "Exit and Install" button does the command by exiting `yad` and using its output. "Install" button gets the selection from a temporary file, so it does not have to wait for the output; `--select-action` is used for updating that file. You can also run the action as double-click action on selection; you do not need a temporary file for that. See `man yad` for more documentation about the options.

As for the icon names I used for buttons, I selected them from among Standard Action Icons specified in the [freedesktop.org's Icon Naming Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html).

If you want "installing" to happen only after `yad` has exited and exiting and installing happen when you choose "Install", use

```
#!/bin/bash

if output=$(yad \
--button='Exit!application-exit:1' \
--button='Install!system-run:0' \
--list \
--separator='\n' \
--center --width=800 --height=600 --title "apps4pi" \
--column "app name" --column "description" \
SimpleScreenRecorder "powerful feature packed yet simple and easy to use screen recorder" \
System-Tools "system maintanance commands all done for you"); then
    printf '%s\n' "$output" >&2
fi
```

You can change the column separator to what you like using the `--separator` option or use the default `|`. Replace the `printf` line with your command.

Comment: So do you accept this answer or is there some problem in it?

Comment: unfortunately I won't have access to a linux computer until tomorrow, I'll tell you once I try it out.

Comment: yes it works, thank you.
but how do I execute a command when selecting a option and pressing install (I'm using your 2nd example).

Comment: That is told in the last sentence: "Replace the `printf` line with your command.". The selection is in the output variable.